# using SoapClient,ArrayObject, ArrayIterator causes error in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-autoloader

I'm working on some helpful method in my entity.

```
private function setApi($api_address,$api_username,$api_password){

    $this->api_address = $api_address;
    $this->api_username = $api_username;
    $this->api_password = $api_password;
    $this->api_client = new SoapClient($api_address); // error
}
```

Warning: require(App/Entity/SoapClient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /zendboilerplate/library/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on line 148 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'App/Entity/SoapClient.php' (include_path='/zendboilerplate/application/../library:/zendboilerplate/application/../library/Bisna/Application/Resource:/zendboilerplate/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /zendboilerplate/library/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on line 148
It seems that zend looks for a class declaration (and it doesn't use included classes in php).

Identical error for each "*new* Class" declaration.
Using a my own class included in library everything is ok. 
(Also tried with @new SoapClient() but no result).

Comment: Is PHP configured using the `--enable-soap` switch which provides this class?  Are you using your own autoloader?

Comment: in controller new SoapClient() works well, in library/App/Entity/MyEntity.php causes something wrong. So I think that's not about configuration.

Comment: I'm using zend boilerplate, I don't know if autoloader could cause that. Where I can check something about autoloader?

Comment: Try a breakpoint/debug point in `Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php` in the function `autoload` and see if it is trying to autoload `SoapClient`.  That should be the file responsible for autoloading in recent versions of ZF.  Something for some reason is making it think to look in `App/Entity/SoapClient.php` for that class. Maybe try putting `var_dump(class_exists('SoapClient', false));` before the call to `new SoapClient` and see what happens.

Comment: Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php here autoload all classes:  
  public function loadClass($className)
    {
        if ($this->namespace !== null && strpos($className, $this->namespace.$this->namespaceSeparator) !== 0) {
            return false;
        }

        require ($this->includePath !== null ? $this->includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '')
               . str_replace($this->namespaceSeparator, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className)
               . $this->fileExtension;
        
        return true;
    }

Comment: Oh okay so you found that its the Doctrine autoloader that is trying to load that class (incorrectly)?

Comment: the doctrine class loader, what's wrong?: http://gamebase.googlecode.com/svn-history/r35/trunk/classes/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php

Comment: Their autoloader doesn't appear to check if the class exists before trying to load it, it just goes right ahead and tries to include it.  Sorry, I don't know much about Doctrine or its autoloader.  You may just need to disable it before loading SoapClient for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is namespace related. Try changing the line that is erroring to:

```
$this->api_client = new \SoapClient($api_address);
```

that should force it to use the PHP SoapClient instead of the namespace that is presumably declared at the start of the file you're having trouble with.